# Не убирать блок если курсор находиться в его области

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть два блока, нужно чтобы при наведении на блок 1 появлялся блок 2 и не исчезал до тех пор - покуда курсор мыши находится в области блока 1 или блока 2.

```js
$("#contacts-view").hover(function() {
  $(".yes-open-phone").animate({
    height: 'show'
  }, 300);
  $(".contacts-tab").css({
    "border": "1px solid #bd2c3c"
  });
  $(".open-phone").css({
    "background": "url('/style/img/close-phone-color.png') no-repeat"
  });
}, function() {
  $(".yes-open-phone").animate({
    height: 'hide'
  }, 300);
  $(".contacts-tab").css({
    "border": "1px solid #fff"
  });
  $(".open-phone").css({
    "background": "url('/style/img/open-phone.png') no-repeat"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contacts-tab" id="contacts-view">БЛОК 1</div>
<div class="yes-open-phone" id="op-pc">БЛОК 2</div>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.
нужно именно на js или jquery, без css

Comment: обязательно на JQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пойти от обрабтного и скрывать "блок 2" при наведении на ЛЮБОЕ место страницы, за исключением "блока 1" и "блока 2":

```js
$('#contacts-view').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(".yes-open-phone").slideDown(300); // раскрываем блок
});

$(document).on('mouseover', function(e) {
  if (!$('#contacts-view').is(e.target) && !$('.yes-open-phone').is(e.target)) { // если наводим не на #contacts-view и не на .yes-open-phone
    $(".yes-open-phone").slideUp(300); // скрываем блок
  }
});
```

```css
.contacts-tab,
.yes-open-phone {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.contacts-tab {
  border: #f00 solid 1px;
}

.yes-open-phone {
  border: #000 solid 1px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contacts-tab" id="contacts-view">БЛОК 1</div>
<div class="yes-open-phone" id="op-pc">БЛОК 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Через `mousemove` и `e.target` получилось как-то так :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('#contacts-view') || $(e.target).is('#op-pc')) {
      if ($(".yes-open-phone").css('display') == 'none')
        $(".yes-open-phone").animate({
          height: 'show'
        }, 300);
    } else {
      if ($(".yes-open-phone").css('display') == 'block')
        $(".yes-open-phone").animate({
          height: 'hide'
        }, 300);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.contacts-tab {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.yes-open-phone {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contacts-tab" id="contacts-view">БЛОК 1</div>
<div class="yes-open-phone" style="display:none;" id="op-pc">БЛОК 2</div>
```

Comment: это не подходит, так как между блоками есть еще разметка. а блок 2 находиться под блоком 1

Comment: если между ними есть еще разметка, то ведя мышь от блока 1 к блоку 2 мы полюбому покинем блок 1 и блок 2 закроется, приведите более полный пример разметки, ато не ясно что там такое :)

Comment: покинув блок 1 мы сразу пападаем в блок 2, так как блок 2 появляется сразу под блоком 1, он практически налаживается на блок 1, расстояние между меньше 1пикселя

Comment: @Денис обновил ответ, может так сойдет :)